# Get IE8 to print the correct iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button

I am having issues getting an iframe printed in IE8

The solution needs to work in IE8 & quirks mode.

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/prq3k/18/

I've tried various variants and most of them print either the wrong iframe or an outer iframe.

I've also tried creating a documentFragment and using .execCommand("print") which works fine in quirks mode but refuses to load some of my images within the iframe in IE8.

The solution can use browser detection to deal with FF & IE8. It would be very ugly but acceptable if it browser detected between IE8 & Quirksmode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing iframe's is horrible. We convinced management to use print stylesheets. Everything is lovely now.

use `css media print`